# Can we modify mysql table collation without data loss?

Tags: mysql

We use  `utf8_bin` collation throughout our app because many columns can contain entries like `AaAaa` and `AAAAA` and require the case sensitivity.  In the future, we'll probably switch just those columns to `ut8_bin` collation, but for now, we're just setting all tables this way.

However, as the sample output below shows, the collation for the `collection` table was somehow set to `latin1_swedish_ci` instead of `utf8_bin`.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM codepen;

+---------------------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                      | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows    | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+---------------------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| collections               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   19939 |             79 |     1589248 |               0 |       688128 |   4194304 |          28835 | 2014-03-15 03:54:01 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
```

My question is, if we run a query like

```
alter table collections convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
```

do we risk any data loss?

Also, the table is pretty small.  Can we do this conversion without a downtime?

```
mysql> SELECT table_name AS "Table",
    -> round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB"
    -> FROM information_schema.TABLES
    -> WHERE table_schema = "codepen"
    ->  AND table_name = "collections";
+-------------+------------+
| Table       | Size in MB |
+-------------+------------+
| collections |       2.17 |
+-------------+------------+
```

If load makes a difference in this question, we do about 125 <s>connections</s> queries per second.

Comment: Why do you have 125 connections per second? Wouldn't you want to have a connection pool? Also have you tried switching the collation on a copy loaded on to similar hardware to get an idea of the cost of switching it?

Comment: Changed connections to queries.  We obv use pooling.  The query takes no time on similar hardware.  Just wanted opinion about safety rather than time for the cutover, i guess.

Comment: Normally the only thing that will hold up a collation change is if you have outstanding transactions or a lot of heavy `UPDATE` type activity. With MySQL you never really know what might happen, so plan for the worst.

Comment: As per my understanding the data will not lost. Already we have done this type of changes. But , I will suggest to take backup or plan for the data security.